# Can Pokemon that hit by Fire Fang get both effect at the same time?

Tags: pokemon-seventh-generation

Fire Fang have two effects that can make your foe flinched or make it burned.

But is it possible that when a Pokemon hit by Fire Fang getting burned and flinched at the same time?

And this question also applied to Thunder Fang and Ice Fang since they're all have two effects getting flinched and paralyzed/frozen the foe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the two odds are independent of each other.

> Fire Fang deals damage and has a 10% chance of burning the opponent. It also has an independent 10% chance of causing the target to flinch, if the user attacks before the target.

[bulpapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Fire_Fang_(move)#Generation_IV), [veekun](https://veekun.com/dex/moves/fire%20fang)